# How do I convert binaries into python objects, add them, and turn the resulting python object back into a binary

Tags: python

This is how I am currently doing it but it doesn't seem to work: First I load two binaries as python objects. Then I add them and form a new python object. Then I save this object as a binary. The resulting binary does not form properly. It throws error when I load it and try to further process it. When out of curiosity, I checked the size of the resulting binary, it was much smaller than the component binaries. For example, if the binaries I am adding are 2.27 GB and 40 MB, the resulting binary I get is sometimes a few MBs and at best, a GB. Below is my code:

```
inputfile1 = open('/path/to/binary/texts1','rb')
inputfile2 = open('/path/to/binary2/texts2','rb')

texts1 = pickle.load(infile1)
texts2 = pickle.load(infile2)

texts = texts1 + texts2

outputfile = open('/Path/to/new/binary/newtext','wb')
pickle.dump(texts,outputfile)
```

The code I used to create the INPUT binaries is as follows:

```
my_path = "/path/to/pdfs"
files = os.listdir(my_path)
doc_set = []

for file in files:
    newpath = (os.path.join(my_path, file)) 
    newpath1 = textract.process(newpath)
    newpath2 = newpath1.decode(encoding='utf-8')
    doc_set.append(newpath2)

texts = []
for i in doc_set:
    raw = i.lower()
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
    stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in stopwords.words()]
    stemmed_tokens = [p_stemmer.stem(i) for i in stopped_tokens]
    texts.append(stemmed_tokens)

outfile2 = open('texts1','wb')
pickle.dump(texts, outfile2)
outfile2.close()
```

This is the error I get:

```
EOFError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9077951a4a43> in <module>
54
55 textfile = open('/path/to/binary','rb')
---> 56 texts = pickle.load(textfile)
57 textfile.close()
58
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: What made you think this is a python.3 specific question?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Is it CPython or some other variant? And does the behaviour change if you explicitly close the file after writing it?

Comment: Its Python 3.8.8